# uninitialized constant SearchController::Instagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to create a web app using the Instagram API. Have created a access token 
which i have added as per the instagram documentation,  but when i add the access token i get the error = uninitialized constant SearchController::Instagram.

I only have a home.html.erb file and an about.html.erb file. So not sure what the issue is , also checked my rake routes as well.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def Home
    access_token = "355030852.XXXXXX.c0faeb3a37a84d4fb96af356dd380269"
    **client = Instagram.client(access_token: access_token)  <---ERROR**
    default_search = client.tag_search('pizza')

    if params[:q]
      search_query = client.tag_search(params[:q])
      @tag = search_query.present? ? search_query : default_search
    else
      @tag = default_search
    end

    @tag = @tag.first.name
    @results = client.tag_recent_media(@tag)
  end

  def about
  end
 end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
    <form action="?" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Instagram photos..." autofocus/>
    </form>
```

**config.rb**

Snapshot2::Application.routes.draw do

```
 get 'about' => 'search#about'

  root 'search#Home'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram is not being loaded. Require instagram in an initializer and that should fix the issue.

UPDATE:
Instagram should be auto-required by rails so make sure you've added gem "instagram" in the Gemfile and run bundle install and that you don't have anything like require: false as an option on that.